# Unable to install conrib.url

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, cran

I'm having trouble installing the `contrib.url` package in my RStudio on Windows. Please note that I am using the latest version of RStudio.

I have tried different means via resources I got online and from the R online community but I keep getting this error message:

> "A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> [https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages%22)

I noticed I need this package because I am unable to knit my `.Rmd` files in HTML and PDF. I was advised to install `tinytex` and `contrib.url`. I have been able to install `tinytex` but couldn't get a way around installing `contrib.url`.

Answer (score 1):

`contrib.url` is not an R package:

```
any(grepl("contrib.url", available.packages()))
[1] FALSE
```

It is a function from the `utils` package, though (which comes pre-installed):

```
?contrib.url
```

It can be used to specify the package type for repository URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how do I go about knitting my .Rmd files as that's the error I get often while I try to do so?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get when knitting .Rmd files?

Comment: The error I get is this: "A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere, see the ideas at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages". But I have been able to resolve it now. It happened all I needed too do was comment out all the install.pacckages() functions before knitting the .Rmd files.

Comment: For future purposes: In rmarkdown documents, you need to specify the cran repository to download packages using `install.packages`. You can either do this by changing `options("repos")` or by passing a `repos` argument to `install.packages`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to knit the .Rmd file now to HTML. All I needed to do was to just comment out the `install.packages()` function before knitting and it was successful. Thanks all for your help!